# How to fill datatable(s) in C# from excel

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I am using the following code for importing data from an excel 2007 spreadsheet tab into a data table.

```
                DataTable dtImport1 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dtImport2 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dtImport3 = new DataTable();
                string strRange1;
                string strRange2;
                string strRange3;

                strRange1 = "A0:I22000";
                strRange2 = "A22000:I41999";
                strRange3 = "A41999:I58432";

                OleDbDataAdapter cmdExcel1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + importTabs[i].ToString() + "$" + strRange1 + "]", connExcel);
                cmdExcel1.Fill(dtImport1);
                dtImport1.AcceptChanges();


                OleDbDataAdapter cmdExcel2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + importTabs[i].ToString() + "$" + strRange2 + "]", connExcel);
                cmdExcel2.Fill(dtImport2);
                dtImport2.AcceptChanges();


                OleDbDataAdapter cmdExcel3 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + importTabs[i].ToString() + "$" + strRange3 + "]", connExcel);
                cmdExcel3.Fill(dtImport3);
                dtImport3.AcceptChanges();
```

Here's the situation so far:

dtImport1 imports the range perfectly fine.

second data table, dtImport2 imports without error but the last record remains partially filled,

dtimport3 doesn't import at all and gives me the following exception:

> "This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet"

How can i improve the code so that it picks up all the rows from the excel without any errors?

**Additional Info:**

I have about 58433 rows of data in excel which i need to import.

Importing from .xlsx (2007 Excel)

I tried to use only one datatable and import the whole tab but it was giving me the same error as the dtImport3 data table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your spreadsheet is "clean", meaning no strange formatting, or data at the end of your spreadsheet?  What happens if you try to just import the last row?

Comment: Can you show us your connection string? Just a guess, but this might happen if you're using an old OLEDB driver?

Comment: yes, the spreadsheet is clean with no formatting errors. Does data table have a limit on the amount of data can be entered? or maybe fill?

Comment: <add name="Excel07ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following article 
[Import data from Excel to SQL Server](http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server/)

Hope that help.
Regards.